# Sendkeys from command prompt

Tags: cmd, sendkeys

Is there a way to use sendkeys (or something equivalent) **from** (not to) the command prompt?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use vbscript. For example, this script will mute the speakers.

```
set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.run"Sndvol"
WScript.Sleep 1500
shell.SendKeys"{TAB}"
shell.SendKeys" "
shell.SendKeys"%{F4}"
```

You launch it from the console with

```
cscript mute.vbs
```

Comment: I'm using :  `Dim WshShell: Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys WScript.Arguments(0)`

Answer (score 12):

Here is a one line solution:
This line will type "**Testing 123**" and then hit **Enter**.

```
echo >script.vbs set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"):shell.SendKeys "Testing 123{ENTER}" & script.vbs
```

Answer (score 1):

Without creating temporary files.
The 'loop' was shown only so that you could open a notebook for output. Remove it after.

```
    @echo off
        :loop
            ::------------begin main code------------
            set command=new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell').SendKeys('WoW{ENTER}{ENTER}');
            for /f "delims=" %%i in ('mshta "javascript:%command%close(new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'));"') do set "var=%%i"
            ::-------------end main code-------------
            timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
        goto :loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank https://stackoverflow.com/a/9710430/3523922 I solved my task to send code without QR code reader, specific was that i send to runed czech aplication Apothéké.

sendkeysAPO.bat

```
cscript sendtoAPO.vbs
pause
```

sendtoAPO.vbs

```
'simulace zasilani QR bez ctecky barcode
'--------
'--------


set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")


' Activate okno s titulkem.  
'--------
'poukaz
    'shell.AppActivate("Apot-4272p") 'v APO prepnuto na sklad 840
    'shell.AppActivate("doc4.docx") 'pro test prenosu textu

'recepto-zadanka
    'kodovani souboru musi byt ANSI jinak nejde prepnout na "Apothéké"
    shell.AppActivate("Apothéké") 'v APO prepnuto na sklad 830


'odeslani 
'--------
''ceska klavesnice

    ''poukaz
    'shell.SendKeys "{ESC}{F9}°FTNP c3e069bc-152f-413d-bab2-567fc32a01f3~"
    
''anglicka klavesnice

    ''poukaz
    ' shell.SendKeys "{ESC}{F9}{~}FTNP c3e069bc-152f-413d-bab2-567fc32a01f3~" 

    ''recepto-zadanka       
    shell.SendKeys "{~}FTNRZ1 | 0222935 | LYNPARZA | 1 | 5706040032 | Abdalla Akbar Bc. | 63032 | Onkologie – onkologicka ambulance | 29.02.2024 | Rath Petr MUDr. | 43ba5fa8-043b-4e8e-a027-1c19e7087039~"

    '{ESC} = klavesa escape
    '{F9} = klavesa F9 = zadani poukazu
    '{~} = klavesa enter
    '~ = klavesa tilda
    '{} rusi specialni funkci pro +/~/^ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys?view=windowsdesktop-8.0
    'odeslani enter pomoci {~} je pro ceske prostredi spolehlive narozdil od {ENTER} ktere funguje jen v anglickem prostredi anglicke klavesnice
```