# How to send a echo text to an open window?

Tags: batch-file

So basically I'm trying to find how to echo "Stop" to an open Command window like command prompt for example. If you can't give the answer what specifically do I need to google to get headed in the right direction.

I have tried googling multiple different ways but my wording has to be wrong as I am only getting info how to send echo to a file.

@echo some text | Command Prompt

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you are doing and why you need to send keystrokes into an open command window

Comment: I don't want to send keystrokes i want to send text to a console just like command Prompt

Comment: echo Stop doesn't work?

Comment: But the issue is that the window's name isn't Command Prompt it is like AwakeningTest so I use @echo stop | AwakeningTest it's not command prompt it's just a console like command prompt

Comment: So, you have an application running called AwakeningTest and it is a console application. It runs until "Stop" is entered and you want a way to send it from a different command window. Right?

Comment: Yes, I want to send it "Stop" it'll send other things eventually but I need to know how to send it stop for now.

Answer (score 1):

This is called scripting or macros. You need to send input into a specific screen via automation (simulating a manual keyboard input). FYI, this is VERY fragile and tends to break a great deal.

This can be done by creating scripts. Example:

```
set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.run"Sndvol"
WScript.Sleep 1500
shell.SendKeys"{TAB}"
shell.SendKeys" "
shell.SendKeys"%{F4}"
```

[Sendkeys from command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709474/sendkeys-from-command-prompt)

[vbs SendKeys only to specific window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45891487/vbs-sendkeys-only-to-specific-window)